# Creating and running a Jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, bluej

I am a **beginner** in java programming. I have created a package called **Comp Project** which contains two classes....

1. **ATM:** It has various functions to carry out actions of atm screen.
2. **Main:** This class calls all the functions from **ATM** and executes them.

Now the program is running good and I have to create a jar file.
I created a Jar file with the main class selected as **Main**. But when I try to run it....it doesn't work. The problem is that i don't understand what creating a manifest is...I looked onto other posts but i did not understand anything.

Can anyone tell me the steps to follow for **creating a proper Jar file** and **Running** it?? I need both as I don't know where i am going wrong.

Update: I am using BlueJ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jar cf yourCompAppJar.jar Main.class` to create your jar file, if you have JDK 6 you can use the **cfe** to specify the entry point.

---

If you are using Eclipse :

- Right-click the project **>** click Export **>** select "Runnable JAR file" under the Java folder **>** In the launch configuration select the class name **>** choose where to save your jar **>** finish.

Answer (score 0):

Create a manifest.txt file.

```
Main-Class: fully.qualified.class.name of your main class
```

> Uses Main-Class as the entry point of this Jar file, when you double
>   click on this Jar file, the “Example.class” main() method will be
>   launched.

And then on command line

```
jar -cvfm Example.jar manifest.txt your-package-structure/*.class
```

Hope this helps.